Howto create a custom subset of cts/vts tests to run
I would like to run only a subset of the modules in cts/vts tradefed.
Is there a way to specify, i.e. with xml, a subset of modules and maybe even which tests inside a module to run?
I would like to start this subset with one command.
I tried to find some tutorial on the internet but couldn't find any.
